# SoapClient converts string "8046618015" to "2147483647" (maximum INT size) when making request?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, ebay-api

I'm trying to list items on eBay using their API and am having a problem with `SoapClient`.

**Overview:**

---

I initialize `SoapClient` like this:

```
$this->client = new SOAPClient($this->wsdlURL, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
```

Then I make calls like this:

```
$responseObj = $this->client->__soapCall($method, array($parameters), null, $header);
```

`$parameters` is something like this:

```
$parameters = array(
    'Version'        => 903,
    'WarningLevel'   => 'High',
    'Item'           => array(
        // ....
        'Storefront' => array(
                'StoreCategoryID'  => $storeCategoryId,
                'StoreCategory2ID' => $storeCategoryId
            );
        // ....
    );
);
```

Where `$storeCategoryId` is `8046618015`.

**The problem**

---

eBay says the category ID is incorrect, so dumping the XML using:

```
$this->client->__getLastRequest();
```

I see the following:

```
......
<ns1:Storefront>
    <ns1:StoreCategoryID>2147483647</ns1:StoreCategoryID>
    <ns1:StoreCategory2ID>2147483647</ns1:StoreCategory2ID>
</ns1:Storefront>
....
```

Clearly, the store category ID in the request is different than what I passed `SoapClient`.

It so happens that `2147483647` is the maximum size of an INT in PHP (or of any signed 32-bit number for that matter, since 2^32/2 = 2147483647), so it appears `SoapClient` is parsing the category ID as an INT and since the "number" is greater than the maximum size of INT that's what it's converted to.

That's my theory.

I tried adding quotes around the `$storeCategoryId` variable when assigning it to the array, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

What is causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why this works, but after some more searching I found adding `(float)` before the variables keeps `SoapClient` from screwing them up.